# PHP RestAPI MySQL Database multiple connections

Tags: php, mysql, rest, api, connection

I have a database class on php which connects to database when initiated and is used to execute queries and return data from database to users via RestAPI request. The problem encountered here is that every time user makes a HTTP request new database class is initiated and new connection is established on every query done by user using RestAPI.

Database class looks like this:

```
<?php
class DbHandler
{
    private $conn;
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/db_connect.php';
        $db         = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    public function getSpotlight($user_id) {
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followers WHERE following = u.id) as followers, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE user_id = u.id) as totalPosts from users u WHERE u.id NOT IN (select if(user_id = :var1, user_with, user_id) from friends where user_id = :var1 OR user_with = :var1) AND u.id != :var1 order by followers desc limit 10;");
      $stmt->bindParam(":var1", $user_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $users = $stmt;
      $stmt  = null;
      return $users;
    }
```

DbConnect looks like this:

```
<?php
class DbConnect
{
    private $conn;
    function __construct()
    {
    }

    function connect()
    {
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
        $host       = DB_HOST;
        $db_name    = DB_NAME;
        $user       = DB_USERNAME;
        $pass       = DB_PASSWORD;
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $user, $pass);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

So basically now when a user calls on index.php a new database class is initiated and every time a query is done there's a new connection established every time and after request is completed it closes.

It wasn't an issue until we got more than 1000 users and each time it increases the response time and I checked the process list on mysql and the connections were increasing and exiting and new connections were coming.

I am quite unsure what should be the solution for this issue. Is there any approach which makes it persistent connection on this DbHandler file? or there's other approaches in PHP we could implement. Willing to hear solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help https://www.phpfastcache.com/
Reduce Database/Webservice Calls

Your website has 10,000 visitors who are online, and your dynamic page has to send 10,000 times the same queries to database or the webservice on every page load.\ With phpFastCache, your page only sends 1 query to your DB/WS, and uses the cache to serve the 9,999 other visitors.\ You can obviously decide the TTL that will matches your needs.